# replace string at pos with char c++

Tags: c++, string, replace, char

I am trying to replace a substring of length 1 with a char - but obviously I cannot just stick a char in there.  Can I do this on the fly? As in:

```
for (int j=0; j <= startword.size(); j++) { 
    for (char i='a'; i < 'z'; i++) {
        choices.add(startword.replace(j, 1, string(i));
```

(but obviously not like that!)

Thanks for your help, this answer is not yet explicit on stackoverflow for c++ (I think only for java).  Please excuse some n00bishness here, I am really giving it everything I promise.

Tyler

Comment: Check the string constructors. You're halfway there.

Comment: string placeholder = &i;
choices.add(startword.replace(j, 1, placeholder));

Comment: Thanks @chris, needed to go back to the basics....

Comment: I really need to be more specific in my comments. Taking the address of that requires there be a null character right after that one, which you have no idea if that;'s the case. I was hinting at the constructor that takes a count, followed by a character. For example, `std::string(5, 'a')` or `std::string(1, i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in C++ the string is mutable and you can use the array operator:

```
for (int j=0; j < startword.size(); j++) 
{ 
    for (char i='a'; i < 'z'; i++) 
    {
        string newChoice = startword;
        newChoice[j] = i;
        choices.add(newChoice);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Cannot index `newChoice[startWord.size()]` ; changed the for loop condition.

Also you could do it like this (maybe useful if `startword` is very long):

```
for (unsigned j=0; j < startword.size(); j++) 
{ 
    char saveChar = startword[j];
    for (char i='a'; i <= 'z'; i++) 
    {
        startword[j] = i;
        choices.add(startword);
    }
    startword[j] = saveChar;
}
```